# how to align buttons in table layout?

Tags: android, alignment, tablelayout, android-tablelayout

I have 2 columns with 10 buttons with a bit longer names and i dont know how to align them.. here is my code.. so please if anyone have an idea how to make it straight?
I have 2 columns with 10 buttons with a bit longer names and i dont know how to align them.. here is my code.. so please if anyone have an idea how to make it straight?

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/futuratheme"
android:gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="25dip" >

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPapir"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/papir" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bInformaticki"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/informaticki" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow5" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bUredski"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/uredski" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPisaci"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/pisaci_pribor" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow4" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bOdlaganje"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/odlaganje" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bPrezentacija"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/prezentacija" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>

<TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="Button" />
</TableRow>
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply this to each tablerow

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content".
```

Also you may want to add

```
android:gravity="aGravityType"
```

(example "left|center", "right|center") to your buttons, that way it will align the text.